# ACF Pro repeater field shortcode for PHP 8.0

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, php-8, acfpro

I'm using FranciscoG's modified shortcode (kudos to him!), but this code no longer works with php 8.0. Anyone who can help solve the problem? I don't quite understand what the error message says.

Code can also be found at:
https://gist.github.com/FranciscoG/c393d9bc6e0a89cd79d1fd531eccf627

The error message is:

```
Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: str_replace(): Argument #2 ($replace) must be of type string when argument #1 ($search) is a string in...
```

The current code is:

```
/**
 * ACF Pro repeater field shortcode
 *
 * I created this shortcode function because it didn't exist and it was being requested by others
 * I originally posted it here: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/repeater-field-shortcode/
 * 
 * @attr {string} field - (Required) the name of the field that contains a repeater sub group
 * @attr {string} sub_fields - (Required) a comma separated list of sub field names that are part of the field repeater group
 * @attr {string} post_id - (Optional) Specific post ID where your value was entered. Defaults to current post ID (not required). This can also be options / taxonomies / users / etc
 */
function my_acf_repeater($atts, $content='') {
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "field" => null,
    "sub_fields" => null,
    "post_id" => null
  ), $atts));

  if (empty($field) || empty($sub_fields)) {
    // silently fail? is that the best option? idk
    return "";
  }

  $sub_fields = explode(",", $sub_fields);
  
  $_finalContent = '';

  if( have_rows($field, $post_id) ):
    while ( have_rows($field, $post_id) ) : the_row();
      
      $_tmp = $content;
      foreach ($sub_fields as $sub) {
        $subValue = get_sub_field(trim($sub));
        $_tmp = str_replace("%$sub%", $subValue, $_tmp);
      }
      $_finalContent .= do_shortcode( $_tmp );

    endwhile;
  else :  
    //$_finalContent = "$field does not have any rows";
  endif;

  return $_finalContent;
}

add_shortcode("acf_repeater", "my_acf_repeater");
```

Comment: and how are you calling your repeater - because at some point, it is trying to replace with nothing.

Comment: I guess you could alter your replacement line like this `if($subValue){
 $_tmp = str_replace("%$sub%", $subValue, $_tmp);
}
`

Comment: @Stender, that replacement wont help :-(

Comment: You are either getting `null` or `array` in `$subValue` and `str_replace` is expecting a **string** there. so you need to debug what you're getting in `$subValue` and then handle the things based on your value type.

Comment: if my replacement doesn't help, then it means that you actually have a value in ' $subValue` - it's just not a string.